# Output of ARM-WB decoder - What is the format? and How to play it?

Tags: codec, amr

I downloaded the 3GPP AMR-WB codec (26.173) from http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/26173.htm and successfully compiled it. However, the file format generated from the decoder is some so-called binary synthesized speech file (*.out). I am wondering what is the exact format and how I can play the the file? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AMR-WB, output will be raw PCM with following properties

- 16000 (16Khz) sampling frequency
- 1 (mono) channel
- 16 bits per channel

You can play it using Audacity or any other player which supports PCM input.